# Paypal sandbox - your shoping cart is empty after i post variables with form?

Tags: php, paypal

I have a problem after I am redirected on paypal site. It display error -> your shopping cart is empty. No idea what is wrong. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">

    <input type="hidden" value="_cart" name="cmd">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="upload">
    <input type="hidden" value="jax.cj@seznam.cz" name="business">
    <input type="hidden" value="super tričko" name="item_name_0">
    <input type="hidden" value="1000" name="amount_0">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_0">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="custom">
    <input type="hidden" value="https://www.yoursite.com/storescripts/my_ipn.php" name="notify_url">
    <input type="hidden" value="https://www.yoursite.com/checkout_complete.php" name="return">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
    <input type="hidden" value="Return to The Store" name="cbt">
    <input type="hidden" value="https://www.yoursite.com/paypal_cancel.php" name="cancel_return">
    <input type="hidden" value="CZ" name="lc">
    <input type="hidden" value="CZK" name="currency_code">
    <input type="image" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!" name="submit" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif">

</form>
```

Comment: I tried to remove input with name custom. Still have a problem with empty shopping cart :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your item variables should start with 1 instead of 0. This is how your item related variables should look like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="super tričko" name="item_name_1">
<input type="hidden" value="1000" name="amount_1">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_1">
```

Comment: Hello thank you for advice you are right I change that but now instead of error with empty cart, paypal display: Internal server error, please contact webmaster@paypal.com for help :) I am very lucky today. When items variables start with 0 -> error cart, now when they are set properly -> interal server error

Comment: Hi, we are aware of this issue and currently working on it. In the meantime, please make sure that your business variable e-mail address is correct and registered under a PayPal account.

Comment: Furthermore, your button is setup for live PayPal environment. If you want to use your Sandbox account, you need to change the URL to www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Comment: Thank you for your wise advices. It works after I chage URL as U said.